# How to pass objective c++ instance in c++ class

Tags: c++, xcode, objective-c++

I am following this URL but i have got struck that How can i pass my objective c++(.mm) instance to c++ class. 
[Calling Objective-C method from C++ method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061005/calling-objective-c-method-from-c-method)

```
MyCPPClass.cpp  
#include "MyCPPClass.h"   
#include "MyObject-C-Interface.h"

int MyCPPClass::someMethod (void *objectiveCObject, void *aParameter)     
{  
// To invoke an Objective-C method from C++, use  
// the C trampoline function  
return MyObjectDoSomethingWith (objectiveCObject, aParameter);  
}
```

How can I call `MyCPPClass::someMethod (void *objectiveCObject, void *aParameter)` from objective c++(.mm) what can I pass the value for `void *objectiveCObject` from objective c++(.mm) class.

Comment: You gave a nice working link with an explanation yourself, what exactly doesn't work for you?

Comment: I am unable to pass objective c instance in .cpp class in method "MyCPPClass::someMethod (void *objectiveCObject, void *aParameter)". How can I pass "void *objectiveCObject" from objective c class.

Comment: There's another way that works for me, please see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42311096/6539779

Comment: What do you mean by "can't pass"? Do you get an error message?

Answer (score -1):

```
We can pass instance of objectiveC class to C++  - 

someMethod ((void*)CFBridgingRetain(self),aParameter)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to the StackOverflow. I'm afraid that your answer provides no explanation nor context. Could you give a few words explaining what exact problem does your code snippet solves?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how it answers the question would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.